# How destroy instance of Protocol on asyncio server after connection lost?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have asynsio server on Python 3.7. 
For each connection, asyncio creates a `new EchoServerProtocol()` object. After receiving the first packet, the server closes the connection, but the `EchoServerProtocol()` object remains in memory. Can you please tell me how to correctly remove it? I understand that somewhere in asyncio there are links to it.

**server.py**

```
import asyncio

class EchoServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.__loop.call_later(5, self.check_connection)
        print('Connection made')
        self.transport = transport

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('Connection lost')

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))

        print('Send: {!r}'.format(message))
        self.transport.write(data)

        print('Close the client socket')
        self.transport.close()

    def check_connection(self):
        print('check connection here')
        self.__loop.call_later(5, self.check_connection)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    server = await loop.create_server(
        lambda: EchoServerProtocol(),
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(main())
```

**client.py**

```
import asyncio


class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, message, on_con_lost, loop):
        self.message = message
        self.loop = loop
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        transport.write(self.message.encode())
        print('Data sent: {!r}'.format(self.message))

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(data.decode()))

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('The server closed the connection')
        self.on_con_lost.set_result(True)


async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    on_con_lost = loop.create_future()
    message = 'Hello World!'

    transport, protocol = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, on_con_lost, loop),
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    # Wait until the protocol signals that the connection
    # is lost and close the transport.
    try:
        await on_con_lost
    finally:
        transport.close()
```

**Output:**

```
Connection made
Data received: 'Hello World!'
Send: 'Hello World!'
Close the client socket
Connection lost
check connection here
check connection here
check connection here
check connection here
check connection here
check connection here
check connection here
check connection here
```

Answer (score 0):

> After receiving the first packet, the server closes the connection, but the `EchoServerProtocol()` object remains in memory.

Looking at your code, it is `check_connection` that is keeping the object in memory. Specifically, the end of `check_connection` says:

```
        self.__loop.call_later(5, self.check_connection)
```

This means: "after 5 seconds, invoke `check_connection` on `self`". The fact that `self` is a protocol that is no longer in use doesn't matter - the event loop is told to invoke a function 5 seconds later, and it will do exactly that.

If you want to have a monitoring task, you should make it a coroutine and **cancel** it when the connection is lost. For example:

```
class EchoServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._checker = loop.create_task(self.check_connection())
        print('Connection made')
        self.transport = transport

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('Connection lost')
        self._checker.cancel()

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))

        print('Send: {!r}'.format(message))
        self.transport.write(data)

        print('Close the client socket')
        self.transport.close()

    async def check_connection(self):
        while True:
            print('check connection here')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

user4815162342 is right. Thanks for your reply. My stupid mistake.

> If you want to have a monitoring task, you should make it a coroutine and cancel it when >the connection is lost. For example:

As for the check_connection method, I just changed my code and added the *del* handler to make sure that the object is being deleted.

```
def check_connection(self):
    print('check connection here')
    if not self.transport.is_closing():
        self.__loop.call_later(5, self.check_connection)

def __del__(self):
    print("destroy protocol")
```